# Laravel - Better way to sort and export data into CSV

Tags: php, laravel, sorting, csv, memory

Im working on a project using Laravel, Im currently having a cron to process data and generate 2 CSV files: 1 is sorted (call file A) and the other 1 is not (file B).

Each file is ~10mb, cron is triggered daily, and we dont need the database to store the results.

Im currently doing something like this:

- Cron runs and stores all the results into a temp table in database
- After finish the process, read data from that table and write to file B (the normal file without sort)
- Then, run another query to get the **sorted** data from table again, then write to file A
- After that, empty that temp table

Coz the result data is too big to store as an array (running out of memory), so we end up with using the temp table to store them.

My question is: Is there any better appoach for this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: If it works and is relatively performant, then honestly, I'd call it "good for now" and move on to the next task. If it really does become a bottleneck, you can look into refactoring.

Comment: 10Mb doesn't sound like a volume of data that would cause out of memory errors.

Comment: Yeh my task now is to imporve that process. Its not critical but we want to get rid of that temporary table (the database) if we can figure out the way to sort that CSV file.

@apokryfos yes 10mb is not a big deal, but thats not the only cron needs to consume the resource

Answer (score 0):

We solved some "out of memory" errors during the export of large data as csv by using cursors.
The "out of memory" occured both with the classic Eloquent method (Model::where(...)->get()) and the chunk function.
You can use cursors this way:

```
use App\Models\Flight;

foreach (Flight::where('destination', 'Zurich')->cursor() as $flight) {
    // write the record in your csv file
}
```

You can find some more documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#cursors